# in Jquery why when selecting a tab via a function the content of that tab is not loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

The behavior I am after is when the user clicks a hyperlink - it then enables a tab (that is disabled onload) and then the content of that tab is refreshed

The behaviour im seeing is the tab gets enabled and then selected but the content is not displayed - if I then click the tab the content is there! weird!

My html

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1" id="addloader">Add a Loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" id="addcsv">Add a CSV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" id="manage">Manage Loaders</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4" id="runLoaders">Run Loaders</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab5" id="addChartSql">Add Chart SQL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab6" id="manageChartSql">Manage Chart SQL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab7" id="editSql">Edit Chart SQL</a></li>
    </ul>

.......

      <div id="tab7" class="tab_content">
          <strong>Edit Chart SQL</strong>
          <div id="editChartSqlData"></div>
      </div>
```

jQuery

```
       $(function() {

         $("#tabs").tabs({disabled: [6]});
      });

  function editsql(id) {

$("#tabs").tabs("enable", 6);
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 6 }); 


var editid = ('id='+ id);

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editChartSql.php",
    data: editid,
    success: function(server_response){
    $('#editChartSqlData').html(server_response);
  }
    });

return false;
}
```

How do I get that content to display in the enabled tab?

UPDATE:

**1) User Clicks Edit**

[image: User Clicks Edit]

**2) Tab is enabled and focused**

[image: Tab is enabled and focused]

**3) When the user then clicks the tab it shows the content**

[image: When the user then clicks the tab it shows the content]

Comment: It's probably the .ajax request that's erroring. Check the error: function to see if that's being called. Or put an alert in the success to prove that's being fired

Comment: good suggestion - it is working the alert popus up but the contents of the tab are not shown - if I then click the tab the contents comes up

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a bug

Comment: Could it be that im calling my select from within a function?

Comment: Confirmed ... $("#tabs").tabs("select", 6); works outside of the function - eg on page load but not when its part of a function...

Comment: @Rob Are you loading content only when u click the tab right?

Answer (score 0):

for ajax call use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editChartSql.php",
    async: false,
    data: editid,
    success: function(server_response){
    $('#editChartSqlData').html(server_response);
  }
    });
```

Comment: If still doesn't work, check the html content of the web page and see if contains the tab data you requested. If yes then I guess the answer by @muthu would be helpful.

Comment: Same thing happened - the funny thing is when I dont have the $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 6 }); - the enable part dosnt work

Comment: Are you sure, your ajax call is made on the first click. If yes, then check for the responce.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to enable the tab which is loaded  currently like this

```
 $(function() {

         $("#tabs").tabs({disabled: [6]});
      });

  function editsql(id) {

$("#tabs").tabs("enable", 6);
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 6 }); 


var editid = ('id='+ id);

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editChartSql.php",
    data: editid,
    success: function(server_response){
    $('#editChartSqlData').html(server_response);
     $("#tabs").tabs("enable", editid);
  $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: editid }); 
  }
    });

return false;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the tab is selected and the content is loading - but the tab just isnt displayed - hence why when I then click the tab the content is there

Answer (score 0):

It could be something really simple like the response is invalid HTML. Do a console.log or console.dir and check what you get back from the server.

```
success: function(server_response){
   console.dir(server_response);
...
```

Comment: the php pahe works on its own with the id - eg editChartSql.php?id=1